# NESTED LISTS: This is a function that is supposed to return a single list and remove duplicates. It however throws an error at line 5

Tags: python-3.x, function, nested-lists

The below function flatten the nested list of integers (List[List[int]]) into a single list and removes duplicates by leaving only the first occurrences.

```
def f2(list_of_list):
    result = []
    for inner_list in list_of_list:
        for x in inner_list:
            for x not in result:
                result.append(x)
    return result
```

If I had my list as:

```
leist=[[0,1,2,2,3],[3,4]]
```

And then apply my function to the list

```
f2(leist)
```

I should get output: `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`

This code however throws a syntax error  at line 5.

```
for x not in result:
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: `for x not in result:` is nonsense.  That should be an `if`, not a `for`.

Comment: Yes. Your code won't run. But if changed as earlier suggestions, it should be fine.  Next time you can try to run your code here - https://pythontutor.com/

Comment: Thanks @jasonharper for beating some sense into my mind. I corrected and it now works fine. I mistook the for for if

Comment: Thanks so much @DanielHao for the link. I have just seen how handy the site is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JuliusFx - try this code snippet for your reference, even you've prob. figured out your original problem.

```
>>> leist=[[0,1,2,2,3],[3,4]]
>>> lst = sum(leist, [])         # flatten all single-level sub-list
>>> lst
[0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4]
>>> list(dict.fromkeys(lst).keys())
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]                  # remove all consecutive duplicates
>>> 
>>>>>> list(set(lst))            # Or can use set() 
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> list(set([1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 1]))  # but Watch this! it'll remove other non-consecutive numbers too! 
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Works well bro. Especially the list(set(lst)) looks cool and a little faster than the dict one

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set` to achieve this and convert back to list

```
result = set()
for inner_list in list_of_lists:
    for x in inner_list:
        result.append(x)
result = list(result)
```

Following your approach

```
def remove_duplicates(list_of_lists):
    result = []
    for inner_list in list_of_lists:
        for x in inner_list:
            if x not in result:
                result.append(x)
    return result
```

The if condition used to check weather `x` is present in `list` Time Consuming : `O(n)`

Comment: when I use your suggestion I get an AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: But I have changed it to result.append(x) and it works fine

Comment: It seem your method is atleast many multiples faster than the second method. Cheers